Confusion about equation 5.55 in Griffiths (4th edition)
I have one confusion about why the surface integral in equation 5.55 in Griffiths (4th edition). I would think  the surface integral extends only over the region enclosing the current. So why has he made it bigger than that without justification? Griffiths exact words are "you can make it bigger than that". If the integration is only over the surface enclosing the current, how can one arbitrary extend the region to infinity where there is no current?
Of course in the footnote it is mentioned that even if current extends to infinity it is still zero, but the derivation is tedious. Can someone tell me how this is derived for infinite current?

Could you actually write the equation so we do not have to own a copym of the book!

Also, the current title only indicates where we can find an equation, it tells us absolutely nothing about what your problem actually is with the equation. So while editing to include the equation as Mike points out, please also edit in an appropriate title.

sorry for slipping the details  I have written it in latex \varointclockwise \limits_S  \frac{(x-x'){(r-r')^3}J.da'

Please add the information to the question itself rather than in the comments, and the MathJaX needs to be written properly in the question

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Your first sentence is missing a verb for the integral, e.g. is equal to whatever.

\begin{eqnarray}
 \int{\bf j(r')}\cdot\nabla
\left[\frac{\bf (r-r')}{|{\bf r-r'}|^3}\right]d^3r'
& = &-\int{\bf j(r')}\cdot\nabla'
\left[\frac{\bf (r-r')}{|{\bf r-r'}|^3}\right]d^3r'\nonumber\\
& = & -\int\left\{\nabla'\cdot
\left[\frac{\bf j(r')(r-r')}{|{\bf r-r'}|^3}\right]
-\frac{{\bf (r-r')}\nabla'\cdot{\bf  j(r')}}
{|{\bf r-r'}|^3}\right\}d^3r'.\nonumber\\
&=&-\oint{\bf dS'}\cdot\left[\frac{\bf j(r')(r-r')}{|{\bf r-r'}|^3}\right].
\nonumber\\
\end{eqnarray}
If $ r'\rightarrow\infty$, the integral approaches
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\oint{\bf dS'}\cdot{\bf j(r')}\left(\frac{\bf r'}{r'^3}\right)=0,
\nonumber\\
\end{eqnarray}
for a spherical surface.
